# Access is denied while accessing same domain iframe height on "http://www"

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to resize iframe on same domain.

This is what i have:

In the head portion of the parent page, i have this:

```
<script language="javascript">

function autoResize(obj){
    newheight=obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    obj.height= (newheight) + "px";
}
</script>
```

Then in the body, my iframe tag:

```
<iframe src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/shop/" width="100%" height="450px" id="iframe1" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onLoad="autoResize(this);"></iframe>
```

Things work well when i use http://example.com and i get an access denied error when i use http://www.example.com.

I tried solving the problem with:

```
document.domain = "<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>";
```

but, it did not solve it rather it worsened it - both http://example.com and http://www.example.com do not work on Internet explorer.

i have seen several questions on this, and it is obvious it is a host, port and protocol issue but am yet to get a solution.

Please, how can i go around this?

Answer (score 1):

`www.example.com` is NOT the same as `example.com`. `www` is just a subdomain, that happens to be the most commonly used to designate the main website. Usually the two are treated as synonymous, but not always.

Try this:

```
<iframe src="/shop/" ... ></iframe>
```

This will load the frame on the exact same domain as the main page.

Comment: this did not work. changed the src of the iframe yet no change in behaviour!